# Get Position of Mouse Cursor on Mouseover of Google Maps V3 API Marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to make a `div` visible at the position of the cursor when the cursor mouseover a marker using jQuery. Its kind of like a tooltip. However I cannot seem to figure out how to get the X/Y coordinates of the point below the cursor.

**Current Code:**

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function(event) {

    $("#tooltip").css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: event.pageY,
        left: event.pageX
    }).toggle();
```

I believe `event` does not have the properties `pageY` and `pageX` like in the event in jQuery.

***How do I get the position of the mouse cursor?***

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is an extension of my previous answer regarding the computation of the pixel positions (Google maps API v3). Introduce a "global" variable `overlay`:

```
var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
overlay.draw = function() {};
overlay.setMap(map); // 'map' is new google.maps.Map(...)
```

Use `overlay` in the listener to get the projection and the pixel coordinates:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
    var projection = overlay.getProjection(); 
    var pixel = projection.fromLatLngToContainerPixel(marker.getPosition());
    // use pixel.x, pixel.y ... (after some rounding)
});
```

You may also have a look at `projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel()`.

Comment: i also solved the problem using jquery without google map api, but youe proposed solution is better :)

Comment: Um, this doesn't get the position of the mouse cursor but rather position of the marker that is listening for the event

Comment: Yeah I wanted the mouse position too, if you really want to get this value @Robin I know a (very hacky) way to get it. I can post it here if you want. It requires jQuery though because it involves deferring the event.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that uses the MouseEvent of the click event but does not rely on accessing that via an undocumented property that can change at any time like 'ub' or 'wb' (I think it's 'ya' currently).

```
map.data.addListener('mouseover', function (e) {
    var keys = Object.keys(e);
    var x, y;
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if (MouseEvent.prototype.isPrototypeOf(e[keys[i]])) {
            x = e[keys[i]].clientX;
            y = e[keys[i]].clientY;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mapObject.marker.addListener("mouseover", (event) => {
  //USE THE COORDINATES HERE = { lat: event.latLng.lat(), lng: event.latLng.lng();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code into the listener function:

```
// to display a tooltip:
marker.setTitle("Hi");

// to get the geographical position:
var pos = marker.getPosition();
var lat = pos.lat();
var lng = pos.lng();
// ...
```

Comment: How can i convert to latlng coordinates relative to the document or to a div?

Comment: The conversion "latlng -> pixel coordinates" is presented in my second answer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that works for me is more straight forward:

```
map.data.addListener('mouseover', function (event) {
    posX = event.ub.clientX;
    posY = event.ub.clientY;
});
```

Comment: This no longer works. You need event.wb.clientX, The overlay answer is the only one that keeps working.

Comment: You are right about ub and wb. I will go and try overlay answer.

Answer (score 1):

This gives the mouse position, works for me.

```
function CanvasProjectionOverlay() { }

CanvasProjectionOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
CanvasProjectionOverlay.prototype.constructor = CanvasProjectionOverlay;
CanvasProjectionOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function () { };
CanvasProjectionOverlay.prototype.draw = function () { };
CanvasProjectionOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function () { };
```

In your initialize function;

```
canvasProjectionOverlay = new CanvasProjectionOverlay();
canvasProjectionOverlay.setMap(map);
```

and use it like this;

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function(event) { 
   var divPixel = canvasProjectionOverlay.getProjection().fromLatLngToContainerPixel(event.latLng);
   x = divPixel.x;
   y = divPixel.y;
});
```

Comment: I dont know why it has not worked for any one other. It is perfect answer

Comment: Please explain why this isn't essentially a duplicate of Jiri's answer?  It also, like Jiri's answer, doesn't provide mouse coordinates.  It provides marker coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

When you hover over a marker `event.domEvent.clientX` and `event.domEvent.clientY` gives you the position on the DOM of where you clicked on the marker. If you subtract the offset, It will give you the center point in pixels of the marker itself.

This will give you the exact center point of your marker.

```
marker.addListener("mouseover", (event) => {
    const x = event.domEvent.clientX - event.domEvent.offsetX,
    const y = event.domEvent.clientY - event.domEvent.offsetY,
});
```