# Google Maps V3: mouse xy position for custom popup clicking on marker, fromLatLngToContainerPixel

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I wanted to do my own js popup while clicking on a marker.
Because I didnt found anything concerning this in the API, I just was
thinking
of getting the xy pos of the mouse, and than "drawing" my div.

Found this example:

[Get Position of Mouse Cursor on Mouseover of Google Maps V3 API Marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558160/get-position-of-mouse-cursor-on-mouseover-of-google-maps-v3-api-marker)

But when I do  console.log(marker.getPosition()) is always 0,0.

Anyone did this own custom popup, and could give me a tip how to do
this?
Shoud I work with "fromLatLngToContainerPixel" or is there another
elegant way?

here is some the code. _spots is a json object.

```
  for (var i = 0; i <= _spots.length; i++) {

      var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(_spots[i].lat, _spots[i].long);
      var spotMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map, 
          title: _spots[i].name,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          icon: image,
          street: _spots[i].street,
          zipcode: _spots[i].zipcode,
          info: _spots[i].info,
      });

      markersArray.push(spotMarker);

        google.maps.event.addListener(spotMarker, 'click', function() {
            console.log(this);

            alert(spotMarker.getPosition());          // -> at this point I get 0,0
            var projection = overlay.getProjection(); 
            var pixel = projection.fromLatLngToContainerPixel(spotMarker.getPosition());
            console.log(pixel);

        });     
 }
```

Best regards,
sv

Comment: marker.getPosition should not return co-ordinates, but a google.maps.latLng. Can you post some code? Sometimes (I ran into this) a marker will return undefined for getPosition unless you explicitly setPosition(). See this http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3023

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i <= _spots.length; i++)
```

This has to be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < _spots.length; i++)
```

Otherwise the last loop will point at a illegal offset.

However, you should use

```
alert(this.getPosition());
```

..to access the clicked marker.

spotMarker will always return the same marker(the last one that has been created)