# Polygon mouseover event position

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

There is a problem on my website. I need to capture "mousemove" event and after that change the position of hint window according to the position of cursor at the moment of event. Here is the code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(country, 'mousemove', function(e) {
      this.setOptions({fillOpacity: 1});
      $('div.info-win').css('top', e.kb.clientY + 20 + 'px');
      $('div.info-win').css('left', e.kb.clientX -50 + 'px');
      $('div.info-win').show()
});
```

At first everything was ok, but soon browser started to show the error, that e.kb is not defined. I checked the event via console and realized that "e.kb" really does not exist. Instead there was "e.lb" so I changed it in my code. But now the problem is the same, and console shows me that "e.lb" does not exist. I cant explain it, but now the captured event has ".gb" property instead of ".lb". can someone help me and explain why this happens every week again , so I need always to check the name of event property?? this is the first time I see problem like that but at the same time I cannot find any solution!

Comment: Don't use internal Google Maps Javascript API properties (like `.kb`), they are not documented and can and do change with updates of the API.  Only use **documented** properties of the API.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Maps MouseEvent doesn't give the screen X and Y values.

Instead, it seems to give only Latitude/Longitude of the mouse position.

Reference:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MouseEvent
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolyMouseEvent

You need to convert the Latitude/Longitude value to the screen mouse X/Y position which is explained here (similar question):

[Get Position of Mouse Cursor on Mouseover of Google Maps V3 API Marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558160/get-position-of-mouse-cursor-on-mouseover-of-google-maps-v3-api-marker)

Answer (score 1):

The reason your map worked for a while and later started failing is that you are using undocumented properties of the MouseEvent object. As you discovered, these may change at any time.

Think about it: do `kb` and `lb` and `gb` sound like names *you* would use in your code to describe a mouse position? And would you change them willy-nilly like that? :-)

So why does Google use gibberish names like these, and why do they change them all the time?

In the original source code that their developers work on, of course they use readable and consistent names. But then they compile the code with a "minifier" that shortens the private variable/property/method names for faster loading. When they revise the source and recompile it, those short names get reassigned arbitrarily.

The three different property names you found over the weeks clearly all refer to the same object in the original source, but the minifier changed the name you see in the browser.

Never assume you can use a property or method you discover in your browser's developer tools - especially if it has a name that makes no sense. Check it first in the [Maps API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference), and if it's not there, don't use it.

See [Seyong's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29952761/1202830) for the details of how to change your code to use the documented methods.